# Azure deployed Web app integration on another Website ( AWS Deployed )

Tags: azure, web-applications

I am creating a fleet management solutions and want to integrate chatgpt in such a way where I can used the data from vehicle manuals, error codes etc, in order to resolve queries asked by the end user who can be a driver, or fleet owner, could someone please help me with this? I am using AWS for the SaaS application so how can I go about integrating chatgpt capabilities in this web app?

So, I found a way using a similar architecture like in given below link: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo

Now, I am not sure, how i can keep using the existing infra and integrate this app into another web app, which is being hosted in AWS for an instance and also can I customize the front-end and backend of it and call as an API is it possible?

I used the existing arch in the above github repo and want to customize in such a way that it can be integrated into another web app